# In Windows XP, how do you create a shortcut to the desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, desktop, shortcuts

Running the command `desktop` brings up `C:\Documents and Settings\User Name\Desktop`. This is different from the top of the hierarchy, `"Desktop"`.

I would like to create a shortcut or create a command that brings up the window you get to when you explore above My Computer, to the top `"Desktop"`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Desktop" is the top level of the Windows shell virtual folder tree. You can reach this folder through the following 'Run' command:

```
explorer.exe /select,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

To create a shortcut to this location:

1. first create a dummy shortcut to any file.
2. Edit the properties for the shortcut and change the target to

   ```
   explorer.exe /select,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
   ```

Comment: Works well. Here's what I did: 1) Create the shortcut in My Documents. It's not really that useful there, but at least I will have it if I ever need it. It has to live somewhere for this to work. 2) Dragged it to the Start Menu. This creates a link to the original shortcut, so don't delete it.

Answer (score 4):

Run the *Fix it* provided by Microsoft at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190355.

Or if you'd rather fix it yourself, here are the steps they provide:

1. Click Start, click Run, type notepad in the Open box, and then click OK.
2. Carefully copy and then paste the following text into the Notepad window:

   ```
   [Shell]
   Command=2
   IconFile=explorer.exe,3
   [Taskbar]
   Command=ToggleDesktop
   ```
3. On the File menu, click Save As, and then save the file to your
   desktop as "Show desktop.scf". The Show desktop icon is created on
   your desktop.
4. Click and then drag the Show desktop icon to your Quick Launch
   toolbar.